# помогите пожайлуста, не получаетса написать програму на python

Tags: python

нужно ввести текст, состоящий из слов, разделенных пробелом. В конце текста - точка. Напечатать все слова, является палиндромами.

Comment: Пошла пандемия палиндронов.

Comment: @nick_n_a, скоро еще и сессия будет...

Comment: Данный ресурс является ресурсом для ответов на вопросы, 
а не площадкой по решению заданий. 
Хотите, что бы кто-то за вас сделал вашу работу - 
обращайтесь к фрилансерам.

Вам следует прочесть следующие разделы справки: 
[Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
[Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), 
[Какие вопросы лучше не задавать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).
После этого отредактируйте вопрос и приведите его к рекомендуемому виду.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Заменяем точку на пустую строку.
2. Делим предложение на части по пробелах.
3. Проверяем слово на палиндромность `x == x[::-1]`.

```
s = 'Hello racecar has a rotor inside.'
print([x for x in s.replace('.', '').split(' ') if x == x[::-1]]) 
# ['racecar', 'a', 'rotor']
```